# Controlling worker thread timeout. Windows services

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Imagine you need to fetch data from a remote server. `Worker thread` gets launched each 30 minutes retrieveing `N partitions of data`.

```
private Int32 timeout = 60000*30;

public void Start() {
    this.workerThread = new Thread(this.ImportDocuments);
    this.finishedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    this.workerThread.Start();
}

// ...

while(!this.finishedEvent.WaitOne(timeout)) {
    // fetch/analyze/process data
}
```

When quota is strictly defined, say `150 documents` per call, should I really use a `timeout`? Would worker thread start again without any timeout defined?

Comment: What behavior are you looking for when the fetch/analyze/process step of 150 documents takes longer than 30 minutes? BTW: the worker thread is never 'started again', it loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wait on a AutoResetEvent **without** a timeout could cause an infinite wait; it makes the worker thread dependent on an outside effect and thereby vulnerable.

That is why I am, in general, in favor of using time-outs.

If there is no timeout, just a `while(true)` (or similar), the worker thread would be spinning continuously. So it would not be *starting again*, it would be looping.